# What does the expression "b=(b-x)&x" mean?

Tags: c++, loops, set, bit-manipulation

Given that x is a set, the following code goes through the subsets of a set x:

```
int b = 0;
do {
// process subset b
} while (b=(b-x)&x);
```

I came across this reading about bit manipulation and how it's used to represent sets.

What does the expression ***b=(b-x)&x*** mean?  How does it work?
I'm familiar with ***==*** but not with ***=*** being here in the do while loop. How does that work? Does the loop terminate when the value of (b-x)&x becomes zero?

The usage of the code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void subsets(int x, int b){
    do{
        cout << b<<"\n";
    }while(b = (b-x)&x);
}

int main()
{
    int x = (1<<1)|(1<<3)|(1<<4)|(1<<8);
    int b = 0;
    subsets(x, b);
    return 0;
}
```

The output given by the above code is:

```
0
2
8
10
16
18
24
26
256
258
264
266
272
274
280
282
```

Comment: The value of an assignment is the assigned value. A non-zero integer is "truth-y" and zero is "false-y".

Comment: What exactly is `x`? What's its type? Where is it declared? What is its first value? How does it change in the loop body?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: please edit your question to include a [mcve]. It should not be necessary to download a book and search for the example to understand the question. Questions should be self-contained

Comment: It's described [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_direct_assignment): _"All built-in assignment operators return `*this`"_. That means `b = a` is a operation (with `int b; int a;`) that returns a reference to `b`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy parts first:

> Does the loop terminate when the value of (b-x)&x becomes zero? I'm familiar with == but not with = being here in the do while loop. How does that work?

Yes.

A `do`/`while` loop like this:

```
do{
    cout << b<<"\n";
}while(b = (b-x)&x);
```

does the following steps:

1. Execute `cout << b<<"\n";`.
2. Execute `b = (b-x)&x` and remember the result.
3. If the result isn't zero, go back to step 1.

`=` is assignment. It sets a variable to a value, as in `i = 0;`. But... huh? What's the *result* of an assignment? In C, the result of an assignment is the value that was assigned. This lets you write `a = b = c = 0;`, to set three variables `a`, `b` and `c` to 0. This is equivalent to `a = (b = (c = 0));`, i.e. it sets `c` to 0, then it sets `b` to the result of that, then it sets `a` to the result of that. (In C++ it's possible to write a class which doesn't follow this rule, but we're only dealing with `int`s here, not classes)

Some people like to use this trick to make their code shorter. You could've written it like this instead:

```
do{
    cout << b<<"\n";
    b = (b-x)&x;
}while(b);
```

> What does the expression b=(b-x)&x mean?

`=` is assignment. `-` is subtraction. `&` is "bitwise AND".

This subtracts `x` from `b`. Then, it bitwise-ANDs the answer to that with `x`. Then, it sets `b` to the answer to that.

What is bitwise AND? Bitwise AND is an operation where you write down the numbers in binary, lines them up, then creates a new number, where each bit is 1 if the bits in *both* inputs are 1, and 0 otherwise. Example:

```
    01011010 = 90
  & 11101000 = 232
  -----------------
    01001000 = 72
```

so 90 & 232 is 72.

> How does it work?

This program is basically treating the numbers as binary. Each bit in `x` is 1 to say something is "in the set", or 0 to say that it's not.

`b` then goes through all the possible combinations of those bits. `b = (b-x) & x;` is a bit of a "voodoo magic spell" to change the combination to the next one in order, for example:

```
  - 000000000 <- b the first time
    011001001 <- x
 -----------------
    100110111 <- b-x
  & 011001001 <- x
 -----------------
    000000001 <- (b-x)&x (b the second time)
  - 011001001 <- x
 -----------------
    100111000 <- b-x
  & 011001001 <- x
 -----------------
    000001000 <- (b-x)&x (b the third time)
  - 011001001 <- x
 -----------------
    100111111 <- b-x
  & 011001001 <- x
 -----------------
    000001001 <- (b-x)&x (b the fourth time)
 ...etc...
```

You can be sure that whoever invented this trick was very clever.

Comment: To answer your question for '=' vs '==', '=' is assignment and '=='  is comparison regardless of where you use them in C++.

Comment: @szMuzzyA `bool MyClass::operator =(MyClass const& b) {return thingy == b.thingy;}`

Comment: @user2553751 That is an overridden operator (a cheat), which does not work on primitive types.  '=' is still called an assignment operator whether it's overridden to do something different or not.

Comment: Still the answer is lacking an insight as to why this formula works...

Comment: @AlwaysLearning You would have to understand binary math in a lot of detail. I'm not sure there is a level between "wow that's magic" and "oh that's trivial"

Comment: I provided insight into how it works here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71931730/15959847. The logic actually isn't too complicated.