# Why does b = (b - x) & x result in getting the next subset?

Tags: bit-manipulation

The [Competitive Programmer's Handbook](https://cses.fi/book/book.pdf) on page 99 suggests the following way of going through all subsets of a set `x` (the set bits represent the numbers in the set):

```cpp
int b = 0;
do {
    // Process subset b
} while (b = (b - x) & x);
```

I understand all the background about bit representation and bitwise operators.
What I am not understanding is why `b = (b - x) & x` results in getting the next subset.
[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62717345/2725810) gives an example, but does not provide an insight.
So, why does this work?

Comment: FYI: Generally, code doing bit manipulations should prefer unsigned integer types; change `int` to `unsigned int`. (This also removes the dependence on two’s complement, which is overwhelmingly prevalent in today’s C implementation but still not required by the C standard.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Things become clearer when we remember [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). The negative of a number is just 1 plus the bitwise NOT of that number. Thus,

```
(b - x) = (b + ~x + 1)
```

Let's work through an example of one iteration of the algorithm. Then I'll explain the logic.

---

Suppose

```
x =                 .  1  1  .  .  1  .
b =                 . [.][.] .  . [1] .
                          ^
```

where `.` denotes zero.

Let's define "important" bits to be the bits that are in the same position as a `1` in `x`. I've surrounded the important bits with `[]`, and I've marked the right-most important zero in `b` with `^`.

```
~x =                1 [.][.] 1  1 [.] 1
~x + b =            1 [.][.] 1  1 [1] 1
~x + b + 1 =        1 [.][1] .  . [.] .
(~x + b + 1) & x =  . [.][1] .  . [.] .
```

Notice that `~x + b` always has a string of ones to the right of the right-most important zero of `b`. When we add `1`, all those ones become zeros, and the right-most important zero becomes a `1`.

If we look only at the important bits, we see that `b` transformed from `[.][.][1]` into `[.][1][.]`. Here are what the important bits will be if we continue:

```
[.][1][.]
[.][1][1]
[1][.][.]
[1][.][1]
[1][1][.]
[1][1][1]
```

If we write the important bits side-by-side like this, as if they were a binary number, then the operation effectively increments that number by 1. The operation is counting.

Once all the important bits are ones, `(b - x) & x` simply becomes `(x - x) & x`, which is `0`, causing the loop to terminate.

By that point, we've encountered all `2^n` possible values of the `n` important bits. Those values are the subsets of `x`.

Comment: In short, adding `~x` fills the unimportant bits of `b` with ones, so they don't stand in the way of incrementing the number represented by `b` as if it consisted of important bits only.